# Weighted Average Grade Book Based on Conditional Dropdown

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a grade book using Google Sheets that produces a weighted average based on three grade categories; exams=45%, participation=30%, and homework=25%. I would like to do this be inserting a drop-down menu at the top of the column, then a formula that will keep a weighted average as grades are added.[image: example of grade book]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Welcome. Would you please explain whether you are calculating the weighted average for the entire class, for each student, or both; and, in the image in your question, which cell(s) contains the weighted average(s). Would you please also explain the meaning of the "4" beside "Class average" and also "Student 1". Would you also add an extra line of data to the image to show the result for student who gets less than 100% in each element of their assessments.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses.

I am only interested in calculating the weighted average for each student. The "4" represents the equivalent holistic grade (not relevant to this inquiry). "Student 1" represents an unnamed student in a class.

Here is a link to a sample worksheet file. There are three grades entered for each category (from the dropdown cell) and a filled in weighted average (not from a formula) based on exams=45%, participation=30%, and homework=25%.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OFAb8R807drvBMosA447gHtBFpQ8DYZ8gWWiIVUVJ1U/edit?usp=sharing